# IEEEtran style BUT with V(N):p-p

Tags: bibtex, ieeetran

I searched for bibliography style like IEEEtran.bst BUT instead of this style

> R. Santerre, L. Pan, C. Cai, and J. Zhu, “Single Point Positioning
>   Using GPS, GLONASS and BeiDou Satellites,” *Positioning*, vol. 5, no. 4,
>   pp. 107–114, 2014.

I Want something like:

> R. Santerre, L. Pan, C. Cai, and J. Zhu, “Single Point Positioning
>   Using GPS, GLONASS and BeiDou Satellites,” *Positioning*, **5**(4):107-114, 2014.

I mean: `vol. n, no. m, pp. a-b` change to `bold volume(number):pages`
Is there ready style in Tex distribution?